# overriding protected method of Superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, protected

In the below example why does the String b prints null and String c prints "gg".

Correct me if I am wrong, whenever a subclass (BClass) overrides a protected method (i.e initClass()) of the superclass (AClass).If you instantiate the subclass. The superclass must make use of overriden method specified by the subclass.

```
public class Example {

    public class AClass {

        private String a;

        public AClass() {
            initClass();
        }

        protected void initClass() {
            a = "randomtext";
        }
    }

    public class BClass extends AClass {

        private String b = null; 
        private String c;          


        @Override
        protected void initClass() {
            b = "omg!";
            c = "gg";
        }

        public void bValue() {
            System.out.println(b);   // prints null
            System.out.println(c);  // prints "gg"
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example.BClass b = new Example().new BClass();
        b.bValue();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the [JSF 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

In the example you can see the execution order. The first steps are the callings of the Constructor down to the `Object` constructor. 
Afterwards this happens:

> Next, all initializers for the instance variables of class [...] are executed.

Since your instance variable b is initialized to null it will be null again afterwards

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the superclass constructor is called before the fields of `ClassB` is initialized. Hence the `initClass()` method is called which sets `b = "omg!"` but then again when the super class constructor returns, `b` is initialized to the value declared in `ClassB` which is `null`.

To debug, put a break point and go step by step, you will find that `b` is first set to `null` and then changes to `omg!` and then comes back to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

There have been already given several correct answers about what's happening. I just wanted to add that it is generally bad practice to call overridden methods from constructor (except of course if you know exactly what you are doing). As you can see, the subclass may not be completely initialised at the time its instance method is invoked (subclass constructor logic has not been executed yet, so effectively overridden method is invoked on an unconstructed object which is dangerous) which might lead to confusions like the one described in this question.

It is much better to write initialisation logic in the constructor and if it is too long then divide it between several private methods invoked from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this example](https://ideone.com/Oy1xoo) explains the issue:

```
public class Main {
    private static class PrintOnCreate {
        public PrintOnCreate(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

    private static class BaseClass {
        private PrintOnCreate member =
            new PrintOnCreate("BaseClass: member initialization");

        static {
            System.out.println("BaseClass: static initialization");
        }

        public BaseClass() {
            System.out.println("BaseClass: constructor");
            memberCalledFromConstructor();
        }

        public void memberCalledFromConstructor() {
            System.out.println("BaseClass: member called from constructor");
        }
    }

    private static class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
        private PrintOnCreate member =
            new PrintOnCreate("DerivedClass: member initialization");

        static {
            System.out.println("DerivedClass: static initialization");
        }

        public DerivedClass() {
            System.out.println("DerivedClass: constructor");
        }

        @Override
        public void memberCalledFromConstructor() {
            System.out.println("DerivedClass: member called from constructor");
        }
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BaseClass obj = new DerivedClass();
    }
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
BaseClass: static initialization
DerivedClass: static initialization
BaseClass: member initialization
BaseClass: constructor
DerivedClass: member called from constructor
DerivedClass: member initialization
DerivedClass: constructor
```

... which demonstrates that the derived class's members are initialized after the base class's constructor (and the invocation of the derived class's member function have completed). This also demonstrates a **key danger of invoking an overridable function from a constructor**, namely that the function can be invoked before the members of the class on which it depends have been initialized. For this reason, constructors should generally avoid invoking member functions (and, when they do, those functions should either be `final` or `static`, so that they either depend only on the current class which has been initialized or on none of the instance variables).

Comment: does this explain why c='gg'?

Comment: when is the initClass() of BClass called and if it is called why does it set the value of c and not b.

Comment: @RossDrew, you're right... my initial answer was incorrect. The assertion that invoking an overridable member function from a base class was corret, but my original reasoning was wrong (that is a property of C++ that is apparently not the same in Java, which I should have double-checked with a simple test program before asserting).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening like this because, first constructor of AClass, which set value of `b = omg!` and `c=gg`. After that When BClass gets load in memory it set `b=null` and c remain as it is which is gg, this is happening because, because in BClass, for b you are doing declaration as well as initialization and for c you are doing only declaration, so as c is already in the memory it even won't get it's default value and as you are not doing any initialization for c, it remain with it's earlier state.